# EDIT: HTML / Javascript Won't Display Uploaded Image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a website via flask, and am having an issue with the site displaying an image.

First, in a form on the home page, there is a checkbox that, when checked, will allow the image to be displayed. There is a function associated with the checkbox that reveals additional checkboxes, though I do not think it has any effect on what I am having issues with (included all the same):

**HTML:**

```
<form action= "{{ url_for('search') }}" method = "post">
  <dl>
    <dd>Plot LIV<input type=checkbox name="testing" onchange="Options()">
    <dd><input type=submit name="submit" value=Search>
        <div id="ops" style="display:none; float:center;">
            <table>
               <tr><td>SE<input type=checkbox name="se"></td>
               <td>RE<input type=checkbox name="A"></td>
               <td>ITH<input type=checkbox name="B"></td>
               <td>VTH<input type=checkbox name="C"></td>
             </table>
        </div>
  </dl>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Options() {
        var x = document.getElementById("ops");
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

I have uploaded the image to a separate URL as a `.png`. When I go to the address in the internet browser, the image opens fine. I try and access the URL from the html using the built-in `url_for` flask method:

```
<img scr= "{{ url_for('picture', _external=True) }}" alt= "broken">
```

This code is in another `dir` that is revealed when a certain value is revealed in a dropdown menu:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="testp" onchange="DispDat(this.value)">
<option value=" "><strong>Select Example</strong></option>
<option value="Example"><strong>Example Text</strong></option>
</select>
<div id="table_tab">
   <div id="Example" style="display:none">
            <table>
            ...
            </table>
            <br>
            {% if request.form.testing %}
                   <img scr= "{{ url_for('picture', _external=True) }}" alt= "broken">                
            {% endif %}

    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function DispDat(key) {
  var divs = document.getElementById("table_tab").children;
  for (var iter = 0; iter < divs.length; iter++) {
      divs[iter].style.display = "none";}
  var o = document.getElementById(key);
  if (o) {
      o.style.display = "block";}
```

I look at the source code when I attempt to display the image, and the URL in the source code is correct: If I were to copy-paste it into the browser directly, it brings me to the correct page. However, all that shows up is the alt text.

Looking at the command window, it posts the data, as expected, and all of the other data that would have gone in the `table` in the second `HTML` script is displayed. Is there something that I am missing, or is what I am trying to do impossible because I have chosen to use a `POST`-method form?

EDIT:
I did notice another error that was popping up in the command window whenever I tried to close the server after loading a page were the image should have loaded:

```
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Could this help in identifying the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. As it turns out, I was missing a `/` at the end of the `<img>` tag. I feel a bit silly...